# how to save what is in a picture box(paint program) in vb

Tags: vb.net, image, save

I am creating a basic paint program in microsoft visual basic 2010 and am using a picture box as my canvas, i was wondering how to save what is in that picture box to your computer, as a jpeg, pdf, or other

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

First you need to save it as .bmp and then convert to desired format.

Answer (score 0):

Use a SaveFileDialog in a button click event...

```
Dim SFD As New SaveFileDialog
SFD.Filter = "BMP Images|*.bmp|JPG Images|*.jpg|PNG Images|*.png|GIF Images|*.gif"

If SFD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    PictureBox1.Image.Save(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work...

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

Private Sub btnSavePictureBox1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSavePictureBox1.Click
    Dim WhateverSavePath As String = "C:\WhateverSavePath\"
    Dim WhateverImageName As String = "WhateverImageName.png"
    Dim bm As Bitmap = New Bitmap(PictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, PictureBox1.ClientSize.Height)
    PictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bm, PictureBox1.ClientRectangle)
    Try
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(WhateverSavePath & WhateverImageName) Then
            Dim overwrite As Integer
            overwrite = MessageBox.Show("File exist." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & WhateverSavePath & WhateverImageName & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to overwrite the existing file?", "Overwrite file?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

            If overwrite = vbYes Then
                FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteFile(WhateverSavePath & WhateverImageName)
                bm.Save(WhateverSavePath & WhateverImageName, ImageFormat.Png)
                MessageBox.Show("Image Saved" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & WhateverSavePath & WhateverImageName, "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            ElseIf overwrite = vbNo Then
                Exit Sub
            End If

        Else
            bm.Save(WhateverSavePath & WhateverImageName, ImageFormat.Png)
            MessageBox.Show("Image Saved" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & WhateverSavePath & WhateverImageName, "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End If
        bm.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: A few notes: **1)** What if he doesn't want it to be the same file name all the time? **2)** What if he wants to specify a custom path? **3)** There's a `.Save` property for `Image` too. Making it into a Bitmap wastes memory.

Comment: 1 and 2 are easy enough to figure out.  This is just an example. 3 I take it since it's a canvas that's being painted on that it would need to be converted to a bitmap, then saved.

Comment: They're easy enough to be a `SaveFileDialog`. :)